# C++/SDL, Tic Tac Toe turn taking

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, sdl, tic-tac-toe

Alright so I have this tic tac toe game I'm making with SDL and C++. I'm trying to implement AI into the game. I don't have a problem setting up the AI, but I have a problem making it where you can take turns. My problem is that when I make my move, I can just move as many times as I want before the AI moves. I want it so I can make my move, and I can't make my move again until the AI makes a move. No matter what I do it seems the turn taking doesn't work properly.

This is the class header

```
class Buttons
{
private:
    SDL_Rect squares[8];

public:
    Buttons();
    void handle_input();
    void load_Squares(SDL_Rect sqRects, SDL_Texture* squarTexs);
    void show_Squares();
    void AI_move();
    int grid[9];
    bool moveMade = true;
};
```

Here I check for mouse input, and depending on the location during the left button press, it sets the according grid value to equal 1, meaning it becomes displayed as a circle on the screen. I also make sure that the AI has made a move before it allows me to click.

```
void Buttons::handle_input()
{
    double mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

    if((event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN))
    {
        //If left mouse button was clicked and AI has made a move
        if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT && moveMade == true)
        {
            //Get mouse location
            mouseX = event.button.x;
            mouseY = event.button.y;

            //If mouse location is in particular square, set according grid value to 1
            if((mouseX >= 0) && (mouseX < SCREEN_WIDTH / 3) && (mouseY >= 0) && (mouseY < SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3) && (grid[0] == 0))
            {
                grid[0] = 1;
                moveMade = false;
            }
            //Basically does this for all other 9 grids
```

Here is my AI function, where I check to make sure the moveMade variable = false. Every time I make a move in the input function above, it sets moveMade to false, which means it should access this function, and only until it finishes this AI_move function should I be able to make a move again, because moveMade is set back equal to true.

```
void Buttons::AI_move()
{

    if(moveMade == false)
    {
        AI_block(&moveMade);
        AI_complete(&moveMade);
        AI_rand(&moveMade);
        moveMade = true;
    }

}
```

Last is my show function, where I show a Circle(player) if the grid array value = 1, and I show the X(AI) if the grid value = 2.

```
void Buttons::show_Squares()
{
    switch(grid[0])
    {
    case 1:
        load_Squares(squares[0], circleTexture); break;
    case 2:
        load_Squares(squares[0], xTexture); break;
    }

    switch(grid[1])
    {
    //Does this all the way to grid[8]
}
```

Alright so my problem doesn't have to do with the AI dealing accordingly, as I haven't even set up my defense and offense functions. My problem is that I can make another move before the AI moves. Sorry if this is way too long, but if I could get any feedback on this that would be great.

Comment: Yes, it is *way too long*  See http://sscce.org/ .  Nobody is going to wade through all this.

Comment: I just edited it and made it a lot shorter

Comment: cout << "This line got hit\n"; I seriously use that a lot, + an identifier to know where it is. Breakpoints as suggested already are good too. Your AI methods probably have a loop break you don't expect.

Comment: Where do you call `AI_move()` and `handle_input()`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting breakpoints at various points such as if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT && moveMade == true) and then following the program through the see if moveMade ever actually gets changed to false?

You should also look at changing show_Squares() into a loop as there is a lot of repeated code using incremented indexes. Something like this:

```
void Buttons::show_Squares()
{
    size_t array_size = sizeof(squares) / sizeof(int); //gets the number of elements in the array

    for(size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        switch(grid[i])
        {
        case 1:
            load_Squares(squares[i], circleTexture); break;
        case 2:
            load_Squares(squares[i], xTexture); break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've had the moveMade == true in that if statement. That's what I've been doing and it still doesn't work. I will use that for loop idea though!